# Read data sequentially in java

Tags: java

I think problem lies  with my text file but i can't understand ??please help to solve out this.
Thanks in advance..

Here is my test file:

```
/*
##Question##
Which is not a JDK component?

##Ans1##
Java SE libraries

##Ans2##
Java SE libraries2

##Ans3##
Java SE libraries3

##Ans4##
Java SE libraries4 

*/
```

Here is my code:

```
public class QuesSheet {

    String strQues;
    String[] ansQues = new String[4];

    public void testRead() {

        try {
            Scanner scReader = new Scanner(new File("mocTest.txt"));

            while (scReader.hasNext()) {
                if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Question##")) {
                    strQues = scReader.nextLine();
                    // System.out.println(str);
                } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans1##")) {
                    ansQues[0] = scReader.nextLine();
                } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans2##")) {
                    ansQues[1] = scReader.nextLine();
                } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans3##")) {
                    ansQues[2] = scReader.nextLine();
                } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans4##")) {
                    ansQues[3] = scReader.nextLine();
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(QuesSheet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QuesSheet qs = new QuesSheet();
        qs.testRead();
        System.out.println(qs.ansQues[0]);
        System.out.println(qs.ansQues[1]);//Why this is not working?? result show s null in both.
        System.out.println(qs.ansQues[2]);//and also same to this??
        System.out.println(qs.ansQues[3]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the text file that you posted contains html tags or something that messed up the contents in the question. Can you edit your question and mark the text file contents as code please?

Comment: I just use "#" as a symbol before "Ans" or  "Question" like "#Ans1#"
The problem is I can't read #Ans2# and #Ans3#.
Though   #Ans1# and #Ans4# can be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I know what your problem is. In your while loop, you have a if else section where you read a line from the text file and check to see which section it is:

```
while (scReader.hasNext()) {
    if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Question##")) {
        strQues = scReader.nextLine();    
    } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans1##")) {
        ansQues[0] = scReader.nextLine();
    } else if (scReader.nextLine().equals("##Ans2##")) {
        ansQues[1] = scReader.nextLine();
...etc
```

What you need to realize is that each time you call scReader.nextLine(), it moves the read position in the file onwards. So therefore the if statements past the first one doesnt execute.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
while (scReader.hasNext()) {
    String line = scReader.nextLine();
    if (line.equals("##Question##")) {
        strQues = scReader.nextLine();    
    } else if (line.equals("##Ans1##")) {
        ansQues[0] = scReader.nextLine();
    } else if (line.equals("##Ans2##")) {
        ansQues[1] = scReader.nextLine();
...etc
```

Now, only the header and the next line will be read for each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Cool Im glad to hear that! If you are happy with it, please accept my answer as the correct one by clicking on the green tick mark on left.